# ZF2 Autoloader: Use factory for base class on extended classes as well

Tags: php, class, zend-framework2, factory

If I wanted to use the same factory for any class that extended my base class, would I want to turn the base class factory into a named function, or is there a better way to do this?

```
$serviceManager => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'someBaseClass' => function($thisServiceManager) {
            $db = $thisServiceManager->get('db');
            $thisBaseClass = new \myNamespace\thisBaseClass($db);
            return $thisBaseClass;
        },
    ),
);
```

EDIT

Further to the answer I accepted, here's the code I've tested that works.

Class File

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class baseClassFactory implements \Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface
{
    public function canCreateServiceWithName (ServiceLocatorInterface $locator, $name, $requestedName = '')
    {
        return ('baseClass' === $name || is_subclass_of($name, 'baseClass'));
    }

    public function createServiceWithName (ServiceLocatorInterface $locator, $name, $requestedName = '')
    {
        $db = $locator->get('db');
        $query = new $name($db);
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Configuration

```
$serviceManager => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'baseClassFactory',
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm following your question, you have a bunch of classes that extend `someBaseClass`, and you want them all to be manufactured in the same way?

If so, then that sounds like a good opportunity to use the `abstract_factories` component in the `ServiceManager`.  The pseudo-code would be like:

```
// warning: untested pseudo-code
class MyAbstractFactory implements \Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface {
    public function canCreateServiceWithName($_, $_, $name) {
        // if I'm asked for someBaseClass or a child of someBaseClass, return true: false otherwise
        return ('someBaseClass' === $name || is_subclass_of($name, 'someBaseClass'));
    }

    public function createServiceWithName($locator, $_, $name) {
        // your factory logic here
        // $object = ...
        return $object;
    }
}
```

And your config would look like:

```
$serviceManager = [ 'abstract_factories' => [ 'MyAbstractFactory' ] ];
```

Using the concrete `factories`, you'd have to repeat the same function for each extended class (AFAIK), which would be a pain to maintain (IMO).  The abstract factory pattern above basically says: give me a class, I'll reflect it to see if it's the base class I care about and, if so, I'll run my factory to get it.

[More info on `abstract_factories` if you've never used it before.](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/tag/abstract-factory-in-zf2/)