# ZF2 Service Manager: How to get a namespace class instance?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, factory

Building on my previous question: [ZF2 Autoloader: Use factory for base class on extended classes as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982221/zf2-autoloader-use-factory-for-base-class-on-extended-classes-as-well)

I'm trying to get an instance of a subclass of a class I've attached an abstract factory for in my service manager config. I know the factory is being called, because I've got an echo in it that is working. The problem I seem to be running into though is that I don't know how to ask the service manager for my class and get it properly.

When I make this call:

```
$x = $serviceManager->get('some\class\baseClass');
```

I get:

```
Error: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an 
       instance for some\class\name
```

And when I output the name that is being passed into the factory, it is missing the slashes like so:

```
someclassbaseclass
```

Class File

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class baseClassFactory implements \Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface
{
    public function canCreateServiceWithName (ServiceLocatorInterface $locator, $name, $requestedName = '')
    {
        return ('baseClass' === $name || is_subclass_of($name, 'baseClass'));
    }

    public function createServiceWithName (ServiceLocatorInterface $locator, $name, $requestedName = '')
    {
        $db = $locator->get('db');
        $query = new $name($db);
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Configuration

```
$serviceManager => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'baseClassFactory',
    ),
);
```

**EDIT**

After testing this code, I've worked out all the bugs. This is the code behind a correct factory accounting for namespaces:

```php
namespace some\class;

use Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class baseClassFactory implements \Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface
{
    public function canCreateServiceWithName (ServiceLocatorInterface $locator, $name, $requestedName = '')
    {
        $baseClassName = 'some\class\baseClass';
        return ($baseClassName === $requestedName || is_subclass_of($requestedName, $baseClassName));
    }

    public function createServiceWithName (ServiceLocatorInterface $locator, $name, $requestedName = '')
    {
        // This class and sub-classes need a database connection
        $db = $locator->get('db');

        // Use the fully qualified path to the class so it inits correctly
        $createName = '\\' . $requestedName;

        // Get the system class instance
        $class = new $createName($db);

        // Pass it back to the user
        return $class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `$requestedName` parameter instead, that's the actual name of the service you requested.

Comment: @Crisp is correct, but just to elaborate, the ServiceManager will lowercase and format all service aliases that you register. So `some\class\baseClass` (which is the `$requestedName`) with internally be keyed as `someclassbaseclass` (`$name`).

Comment: @AlexP Can you submit this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registered service name `some\class\baseClass` is internally formatted by the service manager. The formatting is simply to lowercase and remove any non-alphanumeric characters, which results in `someclassbaseclass`.

When you create an abstract factory, you have the choice of both the name you *requested* in the `$serviceManager->get($requestedName)` method call and *also* the service manager's internal name `$name` (`someclassbaseclass`).

So the only change would be to replace the uses of `$name` with `$requestedName`.

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class baseClassFactory implements AbstractFactoryInterface
{
    public function canCreateServiceWithName (ServiceLocatorInterface $locator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        return ('baseClass' === $requestedName || is_subclass_of($requestedName, 'baseClass'));
    }

    public function createServiceWithName (ServiceLocatorInterface $locator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $db = $locator->get('db');

        return new $requestedName($db);
    }
}
```